# A ring isomorphic to its square

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Is there an example of a ring $A$ (with unity) which is isomorphic as unital rings to $A\times A$?

<strike>Any such ring can't have invariant basis number so in particular can't be commutative.</strike>

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a subtle requirement of the ring isomorphism, but it seems that $A$ can be commutative (though not a domain obviously).

Comment: $A$ and $A\times A$ can be isomorphic as rings without being isomorphic as $A$-modules; the action of $A$ is not the same. So the ring can retain the invariant basis number property.

Comment: @hardmath Shoot, you're right. Oops. Thanks for pointing that out. Also.

Comment: It's a good question, because the distinction between the free-module structure and the ring structure is worth bringing out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$R^{\omega}\cong R^{\omega}\times R^{\omega}$ for any ring $R$, commutative or not. This does not contradict the fact that a commutative ring always has the invariant basis number property because while we can construct an "artificial" isomorphism of rings, it is not an isomorphism of $A$-modules, as the action of $A$ is different. So $A\times A$ really is a free module of rank $2$, and if $A$ is commutative then it is not a free $A$-module of rank $1$.